# Display webpages in a Qt application on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, webkit, html

I need help because I can't figure out how to display a webpage on my Android Qt application.. I also know that webkit and webkitwidgets doesn't exists on Android yet.
Maybe I've to use the native Android webview, but I don't know how to do it :(
PS: I'm using Qt 5.4 on Windows 7 64bit.

Any help will be very appreciated!! Thanks :)

Matteo.

Comment: Nothing, I don't know what to use! :(

Comment: A quick search of "Qt Android Webview" will take you to http://forum.qt.io/topic/29752/android-webkit/7, which will lead you to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32093, which explains that the fix is in https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtwebview/source/7e404f21935999f6aef153dea285ad9c04e29369: (Project for qtwebview). You need to dig deeper next time.

Comment: I'd already found that page but I didn't understand how to use it :( can you explain what I have to do in order to use it? thanks :)